# Split/Filter xml based on field value

Tags: xslt

I have requirement to filter based on the field value for class='G'.

```
<Root>
<Record>
    <emp>
        <empid>1</empid>
        ...
        <empInfo>
            <class>S</class>
            ...
        </empInfo>
        <empInfo>
            <class>G</class>
            ...
        </empInfo>
        <empInfo>
            <class>G</class>
            ...
        </empInfo>
    </emp>
</Record>
<Record>
    <emp>
        <empid>2</empid>
        ...
        <empInfo>
            <class>S</class>
            ...
        </empInfo>
        <empInfo>
            <class>S</class>
            ...
        </empInfo>
    </emp>
</Record>
<Record>
    <emp>
        <empid>3</empid>
        ...
        <empInfo>
            <class>S</class>
            ...
        </empInfo>
    </emp>
</Record>
</Root>
```

The above xml should separate each Record if it has even one 'G' record. So for this only 1 record should be returned with empid='1'

```
<Root>
<Record>
    <emp>
        <empid>1</empid>
        ...
        <empInfo>
            <class>ST</class>
            ...
        </empInfo>
        <empInfo>
            <class>G</class>
            ...
        </empInfo>
        <empInfo>
            <class>G</class>
            ...
        </empInfo>
    </emp>
</Record><Root>
```

I tried using  and  but the complete record is not returned instead it gets split on the no. of  tags.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to select certain nodes from the input document then an XPath expression with a predicate `Record[emp/empInfo/class = 'G']` suffices so in the context of XSLT all you need is

```
<xsl:template match="Root">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="Record[emp/empInfo/class = 'G']"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I need the complete record i.e with all its emp info, if any of its empifo contains class=‘G’. For me, the record is returned but with just 1 empinfo that has class=‘G’

Comment: With this if I check for class=‘S’, it returns all records. As it finds the first occurrence.

Comment: See https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rMrfor my suggestion in action, it selects the complete `Record` element with all `emp` child elements and of course all `empInfo` grandchildren. I don't understand what your second comment is about as there you suddenly change your requirement to check for `class = 'S'`, but of course in that case for your input sample where all `Record` elements have such a descendant they are all selected/returned.

Comment: You might need to edit your question and explain in more detail what you want to achieve, it is not clear whether your use of "split" or "separate" indicates you want several result documents.

Comment: Yes that is correct. I need to have 2 result document. One with class ‘G’ another with class ‘S’. But main concern is, whole record should be returned if any of the empinfo.class matches. So when I check for ‘S’ it should not return record that has any of empinfo.class=‘G’ within it.

Comment: I don't understand your requirement, if the "whole record should be returned if any of the empinfo/class matches" I would the result expect to include any empinfo elements of a selected `record`, otherwise I would not consider it "the whole `record`". Indeed the result you have shown as the desired output contains a `<class>ST</class>` element although there you say you are looking for `class = 'G'`.

Comment: Yes but it also contains class=‘G’. So, if it has all class=‘S’ then only it should be returned. And if it has even just one class=‘G’ it should not be returned. So Class=‘S’ and Class!=‘G’ would be the second condition.

Comment: I think the original problem description in your question is answered, I am not able to make any sense of your additional requirements in the comments. If you have the conditions you want then apply them in an XPath predicate as needed, it might be better to ask a new question for that where you show the requirements, the result you want, the conditions in XSLT you apply and the wrong result.